# Swift 3 - Hide Elements

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Im trying to hide a element using swift 3.  The element won't hide if its in `session.dataTask`, but if I move it outside `session.dataTask` the element hides fine.  Is it possible to hide a element in `session.dataTask`?

```
@IBOutlet weak var login_box: UIStackView!



let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            //Following won't hide element
            self.login_box.isHidden = true
    }

//If placed here element hides fine
login_box.isHidden = true

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to start `URLSessionDataTask` instance using `resume` and always perform `UI` changes on `main` thread.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
     guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
          print("error")
          return
     }

     DispatchQueue.main.async {              
          self.login_box.isHidden = true
     }
}
task.resume()
```

It will take some time get response from server (depends on your internet speed), but if error is not nil then it will not hide your `login_box` because it is return from the block.

Comment: Sorry I had resume, just didn't put it in the example.

Comment: @user2423476 Check the edited answer and put hidden code in main thread like my answer.