# Not able to reload data in Tableview after an array is changed?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, swift3, uitextfield

I am trying to autocomplete the text field using an API (for global equities autocomplete).
The table view with all the array values from the response will be showed when the user taps a text field and starts editing it. I am able to populate the table view when user first edits the text field, but later the table view data is not getting changed.
But i tried printing my array and the value in the array changes according to the entered string in the UITextField.

```
var stockValues = [String]()
var getStockName:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Intialising myCustome Table View AutocompleteStocks

    AutocCompleteStocks.delegate = self
    AutocCompleteStocks.dataSource = self
    self.AutocCompleteStocks.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    self.AutocCompleteStocks.isHidden = true


}


@IBOutlet var stocksAutocomplete: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var AutocCompleteStocks: UITableView!


//TableView Delegate Methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("TejastockValues\(self.stockValues.count)")
    return self.stockValues.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = self.stockValues[indexPath.row]
    print("TejastockValues\(self.stockValues)")
    return cell!
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBOutlet var stockEntryTextField: UITextField!

//Text Field when editing changes . I am storing the text value entered by user into getStockName variable

@IBAction func AutoCompleteTextField(_ sender: AnyObject) {




    self.AutocCompleteStocks.isHidden = false

    getStockName = stockEntryTextField.text!



    print("kichuuuuu\(getStockName)")


    //Calling web service

    Alamofire.request("http://search.xignite.com/Search/Suggest?parameter=XigniteGlobalQuotes.GetGlobalDelayedQuote.Identifier&term=\(getStockName)&tags=xnse").responseJSON{response in

        if let json = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            if let results = json["Results"]{

                print(" \(results)")

                //looping through all the values

                for i in 0..<results.count{

                    let item = results[i] as! [String:AnyObject]

                    let value = item["Value"] as! String

                    self.stockValues.append(value)

                    self.AutocCompleteStocks.reloadData()
                    //reloading the tableview after appending values



                }
                print("TejastockValues\(self.stockValues)")

            }
        }
    }

    callingAutocomplete()

}


func callingAutocomplete(){                                

}
```

Comment: First you need to reload your `tableView` after for loop not inside every iteration of loop, also reload `tableView` on `Main thread`, like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/41478738/6433023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the values into stockValues without clearing it when there is a change in the UIText field. Do something like

stockValues = [""] in the TextField event change, then it should work as intended.And also reload tableView on Main thread as Nirav D suggested.

```
@IBAction func AutoCompleteTextField(_ sender: AnyObject) {




    self.AutocCompleteStocks.isHidden = false

    getStockName = stockEntryTextField.text!



    print("kichuuuuu\(getStockName)")


   //Calling web service

    Alamofire.request("http://search.xignite.com/Search/Suggest?parameter=XigniteGlobalQuotes.GetGlobalDelayedQuote.Identifier&term=\(getStockName)&tags=xnse").responseJSON{response in

        if let json = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            if let results = json["Results"]{

                print(" \(results)")

               //looping through all the values

                for i in 0..<results.count{

                    let item = results[i] as! [String:AnyObject]

                    let value = item["Value"] as! String

                    let text = item["Text"] as! String

                    self.stockValues.append(text)


                    //reloading the tableview after appending values



                }
                self.AutocCompleteStocks.reloadData()
                print("TejastockValues\(self.stockValues)")

            }
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async{

        self.AutocCompleteStocks.reloadData()

    }
    stockValues = [""]

}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

You should not reload the `tableView` from a background thread, always on the `main` thread.

Also, because you are reloading the `tableView` in while you are appending values to `stockValue`, you reload the `tableView` as many times, as many values you have. However, it should only be done, once you have all the items.

Do the following in your `for` loop:

```
for i in 0..<results.count {
     let item = results[i] as! [String:AnyObject]
     let value = item["Value"] as! String
     self.stockValues.append(value)  
}

DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
  //Reloading the tableview after ALL values appended.
  self?.AutocCompleteStocks.reloadData()
}
```